# How to import an entire Azure resource group in Terraform's state?

Tags: azure, import, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Is there a solution to import an entire Azure resource group into Terraform's state file with one command that would capture all resources within that resource group, without manually targeting each resource (which seems to be the only option based on my researches so far)?

Comment: [Terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer) is a bulk import tool.

Comment: Microsoft has since released [aztfexport](https://github.com/Azure/aztfexport). I didn't test it yet though.

Answer (score 4):

Like @dan-monego mentioned, Terraformer is the way to go.
I used it in the past and it's awesome.
There is no official way to do this with Terraform, unfortunately.

If that's not an option for you, you would need to write custom code to list the resources in your group, parse the output and then run the `terraform import` command.

This command would output all the information you'll need to build your import statements `az resource list -g <resource-group-name>`

EDIT: Since Terraform 1.5 you can now use Config-Driven Imports to generate the Terraform config files https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/terraform-1-5-brings-config-driven-import-and-checks

Basically, you define an import block like so

```
  import {
  # ID of the cloud resource
  # Check provider documentation for importable resources and format
  id = “i-abcd1234”
 
  # Resource address
  to = aws_instance.example
}
```

and then run this command

```
terraform plan -generate-config-out=generated_resources.tf
```